# Como alterar o tamanho de uma JFilechooser?

Tags: java, swing

Olá, gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma forma de aumentar o tamanho de um JFileChooser como este :[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ele preenche-se todo o espaço que sobra na tela, para ficar mais fácil de localizar os arquivos. Desde já agradeço, Boa Noite !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente `chooser.setSize(new Dimension(x, y));`.

Substitua `x` e `y` por um valor de sua escolha.

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo :(

Comment: Descobri aqui, no caso seria : file.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));